# ExtJS 4 Chart - Change with Ajax store

Tags: extjs, charts, store

I have some trouble with my app. I have a chart and the data are loaded from a store who make an Ajax connection.
The first time I load my page it work fine but I have three buttons and my goal is to load a new chart to replace the previous when someone click on a button but this doesn't work like I want. I have some bugs and I want to know if there a "official" way to do what I want to do.

I have an error:

```
Error : TypeError: me.labels[inflections.length - 1] is undefined
Source File : extjs-4.1.0/ext-all-debug.js
Ligne : 58728
```

When someone click on a button I do this:

```
var el = Ext.get('GraphVolumeBar03');
                if(!el) {
                    var elem = Ext.create('Axiastats.view.GraphVolumeBar03');
                     Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        id : 'GraphVolumeBar03',
                        renderTo: 'graphContainer-body',
                        height : 300,
                        border: false,
                        items: elem,
                    });
                }
                else {
                    el.show();
                    Ext.getCmp('GraphVolumeBar03-chart').redraw(true);
                }
```

And I hide the old charts but I don't think it's the right solution:

```
var el2 = Ext.get('GraphVolumeBar01');
                 if(el2) { el2.hide(); }
                 var el3 = Ext.get('GraphVolumeBar02');
                 if(el3) { el3.hide(); }
```